# Uniform convergence on compact sets and on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I am trying to determine where the series of functions $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x \sin(n^2x)}{n^2}$ is uniformly convergent. I already determined that the convergence is uniform for $x \in S \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $S$ is compact.  When $S$ is compact then $|x| \leq C$ for some constant $C$ and

$$\left|\frac{x \sin(n^2x)}{n^2}\right| = \frac{|x||\sin(n^2x)|}{n^2} \leq \frac{C}{n^2}$$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{C}{n^2}$ converges the Weierstrass test implies uniform convergence.
I also want to determine if the convergence is uniform on $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $x$ can be unbounded.

It is not clear to me how to prove or disprove uniform convergence on the entire real line.

Comment: Is the nth term $x\sin(n^2x)/n^2$ as in your Weierstrass test? I assumed the $x$ in front of the first sum was a typo. Otherwise the problem is much simpler.

Comment: @RRL: I apologize.  That is indeed a typo which I just edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $N \geqslant N_0, x \in \mathbb{R}$  we would have

$$\left|x\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n^2}\right|=  \left|x\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(N+j)^2x)}{(N+j)^2}\right|< \epsilon,$$

and it would follow that $\displaystyle \left|\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\sin((N+j)^2x_q)}{(N+j)^2}\right|   < \frac{\epsilon}{x_q}$ for all $q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_q = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2q\pi$.

Note that $\sin((N+j)^2x_q)  = \sin\left((N+j)^2\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ which equals $0$ if both $N$ and $j$ are odd and equals $\sin\left(N^2 \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \pm 1$ if $N$ is odd and $j = 2k$ is even.

Hence, for any odd $N \geqslant N_0$ and all $q \in \mathbb{N}$ we have

$$\frac{\epsilon}{x_q} > \left|\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\sin((N+j)^2x_q)}{(N+j)^2}\right| = \left|\sin\left(N^2 \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right| \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(N+2k)^2} =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(N+2k)^2} $$

This is impossible as the LHS converges to $0$ as $q \to \infty$ and the series on the RHS converges to a positive value.  Therefore, the convergence is not uniform on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you clarify how you get $\sin((N+j)^2x_q) = 0$ and $\pm 1$?

Comment: First $(N+j)^2 x_q$ equals $(N+j)^2 \frac{\pi}{2}$ plus an integer multiple of $2\pi$, so $\sin((N+j)^2 x_q) = \sin((N+j)^2\frac{\pi}{2}$.  If $N = 2M+1$ (odd) and $j = 2k+1$ (odd) then $(N+j)^2 \frac{\pi}{2} = 4(M+k+1)^2\frac{\pi}{2} = (M+k+1)^2 2\pi$ and $\sin(...) = 0$.

Comment: If $N = 2M+1$ and $j = 2k$ then $(N+j)^2 \frac{\pi}{2} = N^2\frac{\pi}{2} + (Nk + k^2)2\pi$ and $\sin(...) = \sin (N^2 \frac{\pi}{2}) = \pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks. This is clear to me now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_m(x)=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac {x\sin (n^2x)}{n^2}.$

If $(f_m)_{m\in \Bbb N}$ converged uniformly on $\Bbb R$ then $0=\lim_{m\to \infty}\|f_m-f_{m-1}\|_{\Bbb R}$ where $\|f_m-f_{m-1}\|_{\Bbb R}=\sup \{|f_m(x)-f_{m-1}(x)|:x\in \Bbb R\}.$

But with $x_m=m^2\pi +\frac {\pi}{2m^2}$ we have, for $m>1,$ that $$\|f_m-f_{m-1}\|_{\Bbb R}\ge |f_m(x_m)-f_{m-1}(x_m)|=$$ $$=\left| \frac {x_m\sin (m^2x_m)}{m^2}\right|=$$  $$=\frac {x_m}{m^2}>\frac {m^2\pi}{m^2}=\pi.$$

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately there should be no $x$ before the sum. It was a typo that I corrected. I do understand your answer and I gave it an upvote.

Comment: I have amended my A to fit the amended Q.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the series converges uniformly.

So exists $m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$A:=\sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}}\left|\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin{n^2x}}{n^2}\right|<1$$

But $A \geq \limsup_{x \to +\infty} |x| \left|\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{n^2x}}{n^2}\right|=+\infty$

since

$\left|\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin{n^2x}}{n^2}\right| \leq C,\forall x \in \Bbb{R}$
Apply the same argument for unbounded subsets of the real line.